# Using expected value to prove that there is a line intersecting at least 4 of the circles

Tags: probability

There are several circles inside a square of side length $1$. The sum of the circumferences of the circles is $10$. Prove that there exists a line that intersects at least $4$ of the circles.

---

I know I have to use expected value to prove this, but how?  Casework wouldn't possibly work and I can't really think of other stratigies.  Thanks in advanced for providing a solution!

Answer (score 3):

**Basic approach.** Let the unit square be the square bounded by the four lines $x = 0$, $x = 1$, $y = 0$, and $y = 1$.  Further let $f(u)$ be the number of circles that intersect the vertical line $x = u$.  What is the expected value of $f(u)$ over the interval $[0, 1]$?  In other words, what is $\int_{u=0}^1 f(u) \, du$?  What can you say about the *maximum* of $f(u)$ over that same interval?

This is more or less a variation on the pigeonhole principle.